# How many variable checks should you do?

Tags: php, variables

Something I've never been sure about is how many variable checks to do in PHP.  For example take the following piece of code.  I am not checking any of the variables before I assign them or pass them to a function to see if they contain what I expect

```
$carId = '12';
$aCar = fetchCar($carId);

$make = $aCar['make'];
$model = $aCar['model'];
$yearMade = $aCar['year'];
$age = calcAge($yearMade);
```

Now if I add some checks

```
$carId = '12';

if(is_numeric($carId))
{
    $aCar = fetchCar($carId);

    if(isset($aCar['make']) && is_string($aCar['make']))
    {
        $make = $aCar['make'];
    }
    else
    {
        //Report error
    }

    if(isset($aCar['model']) && is_string($aCar['model']))
    {
       $model = $aCar['model'];
    }
    else
    {
        //Report error
    }

    if(isset($aCar['year']) && is_numeric($aCar['year']))
    {
        $yearMade = $aCar['year'];
        $age = calcAge($yearMade);
    }
    else
    {
        //Report error
    }
}
else
{
    //Report errors
}
```

The code is now better but is it a bit too excessive and bloated?  Should I be doing this many checks?

If I shouldn't be doing this many checks where do you draw the line between what you should and shouldn't check?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, you open your `isset(` but do not close it.

Comment: Depends. What are all the possible return values for `fetchCar()`? Take that in consideration and do the checks you need to ensure that your script will run without errors.

Comment: @MMM Thanks, I've changed those

Comment: Check your variables on what you expect them to be, I'd say. But couldn't you even "easify" this code? like so: `if (isset($a, $b) && is_string($a) && is_numeric($b)) {}` So that you only have one if condition? Depends of course on what you want to achieve...

Comment: I think it belongs to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the dilemma of a dynamic type language.
It depends heavily on what fetchCar() function is doing.

The approach i would take is assume fetchCar is returning a car array or throwing exception. 
If you combine this with good exception handling logic you can end up with clean and stable code.

For example:

```
function fetchCar($id) {

    $car = queryDatabaseSomehow();
    if (empty($car)) {
        throw new ExceptionNotFound();
    }
    //eventually you can put your type checking here?
    if (!isset($car['x']) || !is_string($car['x'])) {
        throw new ExceptionDb();
    }
}

echo fetchCar(3)['make'];
```

Also if you would like to do this super-proper and go fully OOP, Car should become a class with make,model and year as its members. fetchCar() would return Car or throw Exception. But this is not always desirable of course.

Answer (score 0):

I rather turn it all into a function that can be reused for these cases.

```
function check_keys($arr_check, $arr_cond) {

    $boo_success = TRUE;
    foreach(array_keys($arr_cond) as $h)
        if (in_array($arr_cond[$h], array('is_string', 'is_numeric'))) {
            if ( ! isset($arr_check[$h]) or ! ($arr_cond[$h]($arr_check[$h]))) {

                $boo_success = FALSE;
                echo "The key {$h} is missing!";
                // If run through a class, $this->errors[] = 'error message';

            }
        } else {

            $boo_success = FALSE;
            echo 'Invalid function';

        }

    return $boo_success;

}

$arr_keys = array('make'  => 'is_string',
                  'model' => 'is_string',
                  'year'  => 'is_numeric');

if (check_keys($aCar, $arr_keys)) {

    // Run successful stuff

}
```

Comment: not everything needs to be string

Comment: smart. but notice how super-slow it will work.

Comment: Could you elaborate why it would be super slow?

Comment: PHP is super slow anyway.

Comment: lots of big, mature, large-traffic projects are running on PHP so it is definitely not super slow. I think you just need to know what constructs to avoid. For example call_user_func and/or calling function by name like we have here will work slow as op-code cache will not handle it.

Comment: Well, PHP is interpretted, isn't `"func_name"()` same as `func_name()` ? Its not translated so it has to seek for function by names all the times, doesnt it?

Comment: @kajacx "func_name"() will work at least few times slower than func_name(). you can do a simple for loop to do it 100 times if you don't believe me. PHP is not interpreted on the fly. it is tokenised, converted to byte-code, sometimes this byte-code is cached. ask another SO question if you want to know details :)

Comment: If it's an urgent case to be addressed, a simple `switch(...) { case 'is_string':` would do it I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that some people haven't noticed. Be wary of using `is_string`:

```
<?php
$var = "test";
$var['something'] = 2;

if(is_string($var['something'])) {
    echo "Hello world!"; // Will echo this because $var is a string!

} else {
    echo "Hello hell!";
}
echo "<br/>";
echo $var['something']; // returns 2
?>
```

[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/445-sba).

Compare it with this:

```
$var = array('something' => 2);

if(is_string($var['something'])) {
    echo "Hello world!"; // $var is now an array

} else if (is_numeric($var['something'])) {
    echo "Hello hell!"; // Will echo this because $var is string!
}
echo "<br/>";
echo $var['something'];
```

You need to check whether `$var` is an array, as it might give you unexpected results. `isset($var['something'])` will return true in the first example.

To answer your question, I don't think those are too many checks. It really depends on what `fetchCar()` does and how it gets the data. If you can't trust it (say, it's based on user data) then you should perform all these checks. If not, then there is no point really.